# React - i18next-extract: Question about extractedTranslations output

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, i18next, react-i18next, babel-plugin

I'm using this babel plugin https://github.com/gilbsgilbs/babel-plugin-i18next-extract.  Haven't configured it much beyond the basics.

it generates an extractedTranslations folder but I just end up with keys and no values.  Is that the correct behavior?  I would figure that it would reconcile the values from the translations files that i already have..  I'm kind of confused on how this is useful?

Answer (score 2):

Creator of the plugin here. By default, babel-plugin-i18next-extract indeed extracts the keys to `extractedTranslations/{{locale}}/{{ns}}.json`. If you want to change this, you must set the [`outputPath`](https://i18next-extract.netlify.com/#/configuration?id=outputpath) configuration option to something else. For instance:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "i18next-extract",
      {
        "outputPath": "locales/{{locale}}/{{ns}}.json"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

If the `outputPath` you set already exists for a given locale and namespace, the plugin should only add new keys and leave the values of existing keys untouched.

You may want to look at the other [configuration options](https://i18next-extract.netlify.com/#/configuration) to make the plugin match to your workflow.